# Does proguard support multirelease jars?

Tags: java, log4j2, proguard, multi-release-jar

We have a multirelease .jar that contains different .class files under META-INF/versions (e. g. META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class). After running proguard in version 7.2.1, the META-INF/versions folder in the obfuscated .jar is empty.

Does proguard support obfuscating classes under META-INF/versions in general?

If yes, how must it be done correctly?

And if not, what would be the way to convert an multirelease.jar into a non-multirelease.jar for a given version?